# Text area adding extra <br> tags

Tags: php

I have a simple CMS that allows admins to update text through textarea fields in forms. Unfortuantely, once a br tag is introduced into the textfield, each time the user clicks the submit button, an extra br tag is added next to each existing one. I think it's because my nl2br function is creating a duplicate br tag each time the form is submitted. I tried to trim the post data, to str_replace the br with a n linebreak, and to set wrap to soft and hard, all to no avail. the inclusion or exclusion of htmlentities has no effect. This is the essence of what I'm trying to do:

```
<?php
function echo_homepage($name) {
global $connection;
$query = "SELECT info FROM homepage WHERE name = '{$name}'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);    
confirm_query($result);
$data_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$info = $data_array["info"];
$info = htmlentities($info);
echo nl2br($info);
}

if(isset($_POST["field1"]) || isset($_POST["field2"])) {
    $field1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $field1);
    $field2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $field2);
    $query1 = "UPDATE homepage SET info='{$field1}' WHERE name='field1' LIMIT 1";
    $query2 = "UPDATE homepage SET info='{$field2}' WHERE name='field2' LIMIT 1";
    $result1 = mysqli_query($connection, $query1);
    $result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="edit_homepage.php" method="post">
    <fieldset id="" title="Left Column of Text">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <textarea name="field1" id="info1" cols="50" rows="8" ><?php echo_homepage("field1"); ?></textarea>
            </li>   
        </ol>   
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="" title="Right Column of Text">
        <ol>
            <li>
                <textarea name="field2" id="info1" cols="50" rows="8"  ><?php echo_homepage("field2"); ?></textarea>
            </li>
        </ol> 
        <button type="submit">Update Text</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The form populates the textarea with the text already in the mysql field. Everything works fine until a br tag is present (which I want). Once the br tag is present, each time the user hits the submit button, an extra br tag is placed adjacent to the old one. I need the users to be able to hit enter and create a line space, but I can't have the extra br tag added when they hit the submit button for the form.

Thanks very much for reading.

EDIT - ANSWER

Ok, thanks to @eX0du5 for the reference to the comments below. Most of the helper functions from the comments didn't work, but I finally found a solution by rewriting the function that outputs the text by including this function from the comments (the only one of them that worked in this case):

```
function nl2br2($string) {
$string = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "<br />", $string);
return $string;
}
```

I replaced the last line of echo_homepage with this:

```
echo br2nl($info);
```

I found similar questions in about seven posts, all with no clear answers, so I hope that helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you remove the `<br>` before you escape the string and insert it into the database? You will not loose your newline `\n` with `nl2br()` according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php) (see comments). So it is enough to get rid of the `<br>` again.

I am not sure if you want to allow HTML code at all. If not, you should remove all HTML tags with [strip_tags](https://secure.php.net/strip_tags).

This would make it also harder to have XSS attacks against your page.

Comment: Thanks! You mean like this? $field1 = str_replace("<br>","",$field1); I threw that in but it still printed out my br tags. 

Good idea about the HTML but this is my backend admin form. The echohomepage function is used to populate the textarea here on the backend form and also to spit out the text on the homepage when it loads.

Comment: I tried to strip it, too but the br tags are still there
$field1 = strip_tags($field1, '<br><br/>');

Comment: Check the database content and not the printout first. If the tags are already stored at the database, each new save will add additional ones. So you need to make sure it never reaches the database. Your attempt to remove it with str_replace might fail if the php command produces <br />. Check the produced HTML and see what you would have to remove.

Comment: Thanks. I'm updating the text through forms in the backend. When the backend pages load, I'm populating the textareas with the fields to edit from the database. The data comes all inline with br tags. Before, when I hit the submit button, extra br tags would appear in the text fields. The rewritten nl2br function fixes it. Now, I had to explain to my client what the br tags meant, but they were ok with that.